# NullReferenceException thrown when appending child to xml document

Tags: c#, xml

I have an aspx page that accepts 3 user inputs called

1. Name
2. Date
3. Description

I want to create an xml document using these. When I try to append the child, I get a NullReferenceException with a detail of

`{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

Here is my code

```
            string name = EventName.Text;
            string date = DatePicker.SelectedDate.ToString();
            string description = NewsDescription.Text;

            //Create XML Document
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            //Event Name
            XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("Name");
            XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode(name.ToString());
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(text);

            //Event Date
            XmlElement elem2 = doc.CreateElement("Date");
            XmlText text2 = doc.CreateTextNode(date.ToString());
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem2);
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(text2);

            //Event Description
            XmlElement elem3 = doc.CreateElement("Description");
            XmlText text3 = doc.CreateTextNode(description.ToString());
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem3);
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(text3);

            doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

[image: Visual Studio Screen shot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. Just check the objects involved to see which one is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentElement.AppendChild throws object reference not set to an instance of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276229/documentelement-appendchild-throws-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an)

Comment: Exactly the same issue faced in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276229/documentelement-appendchild-throws-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doc` has no Element yet.

```
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("Name"); // is just declaration
```

So,

```
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
```

Should be:

```
doc.AppendChild(elem);
```